# ¿Cómo importar un archivo csv a un nparray?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en Python 3, para ello dispongo de un archivo llamado movies.csv

Este archivo tiene información separada por comas:

```
movieId,title,genres
```

Necesito agrupar todos los movieId existentes en el archivo, en un ndarray. Para luego, pedir por teclado nuevos movieId y verificar si no está repitiendo un movieId ya existente.

Si alguien puede ayudarme, se lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: ¿Qué intentaste, Jhoss?

Answer (score 1):

Pandas ya dispone de una función llamada read_csv que hace dicha tarea

Un ejemplo sería:

```
import pandas as pd

delimitador = ','
df = pd.read_csv(archivo,delimitador)
```

Puedes encontrar más información sobre el método [aqui](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) como por ejemplo, como indicarle los nombre de columnas, en la documentación también existen métodos para agrupar por el nombre de una columna.

Adicionalmente, una vez leído el csv, puedes seleccionar la columna que quieras y pasarla a un numpy array. En este caso:

```
df['movieId'].toarray()
```

Answer (score 0):

Para leer un csv puedes usar la funcion [genfromtxt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html#numpy.genfromtxt):

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
data = genfromtxt('movies.csv', delimiter=',')
```

Comment: Solo para que conste, las funciones `numpy` de acceso a CSV son extremadamente lentas y eso se nota cuando se están leyendo archivos muy grandes. La implementación de `pandas` es al menos 10 veces más rápida.